# Mockito error- There were zero interactions with this mock Android

Tags: java, android, mockito, android-testing, testcase

I am getting **Wanted but not invoked. There were zero interactions with this mock** error for `checkFingerPrintWhenTouchIdEnabled()` method at line `verify(fingerPrintHelper, times(1)).initializeFingerPrint(any());`
    .
    Even I have mocked the object & while debugging `initializeFingerPrint(..)` function gets called.

Below is the function which I want to test,

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public void checkFingerPrint() {
    if (fingerPrintHelper.isDeviceReadyForFingerPrint()) {
        boolean isFingerPrintEnable = sharedPreference.getBoolean(SpKeys.KEY_FINGER_PRINT, false);
        if (isFingerPrintEnable) {
            fingerPrintHelper.initializeFingerPrint(this);
        }
    } else {
        sharedPreference.putBoolean(SpKeys.KEY_FINGER_PRINT, false).commit();
    }
}
```

LoginActvity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public FingerPrintHelper fingerPrintHelper;
ActivityLoginBinding binding;
private LoginViewModel loginViewModel;
private SharedPreferenceManager sharedPreferenceManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    sharedPreferenceManager = new SharedPreferenceManager(getApplicationContext(), SpKeys.MY_SP);
    fingerPrintHelper = new FingerPrintHelper(this);
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_login);
    loginViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel.class);
    binding.setViewModel(loginViewModel);
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);

    checkFingerPrint();
}


@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public void checkFingerPrint() {
    if (fingerPrintHelper.isDeviceReadyForFingerPrint()) {
        boolean isFingerPrintEnable = sharedPreferenceManager.getBoolean(SpKeys.KEY_FINGER_PRINT, false);
        if (isFingerPrintEnable) {
            fingerPrintHelper.initializeFingerPrint(this);
        }
    } else {
        sharedPreferenceManager.setBoolean(SpKeys.KEY_FINGER_PRINT, false);
    }
}
}
```

I am writing both positive and negative test cases for this function whereas `checkFingerPrintWhenTouchIdDisabled()` test works fine, but I am getting error for `checkFingerPrintWhenTouchIdEnabled()` test function
Please refer the below test class

LoginActivityTest.java

```
public class LoginActivityTest {

LoginActivity loginActivity;
@Mock
FingerPrintHelper fingerPrintHelper;
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity> loginActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
        LoginActivity.class);
Context context;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    loginActivity = loginActivityRule.getActivity();
    context = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
}

@Test
public void checkFingerPrintWhenTouchIdDisabled() {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SpKeys.MY_SP, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    when(fingerPrintHelper.isDeviceReadyForFingerPrint()).thenReturn(false);
    loginActivity.checkFingerPrint();
    Assert.assertFalse(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(SpKeys.KEY_FINGER_PRINT, false));
    verify(fingerPrintHelper, never()).initializeFingerPrint(any());

}
@Test
public void checkFingerPrintWhenTouchIdEnabled() {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SpKeys.MY_SP, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    when(fingerPrintHelper.isDeviceReadyForFingerPrint()).thenReturn(true);
    preferencesEditor.putBoolean(SpKeys.KEY_FINGER_PRINT, true).commit();

    loginActivity.checkFingerPrint();

    /* Below verification for `initializeFingerPrint()` is throwing error as,
    Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock. error,
    Even I have mock the object & while debugging the method is getting invoked also.
    If I debug my code it calls this function but in test cases it shows above error
    */
    verify(fingerPrintHelper, times(1)).initializeFingerPrint(any());
}
}
```

Then why am I getting the **zero interaction** error for my test cases? What could be the issue, any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @second Sorry for the inconvenience. I have updated the file.

Comment: The exception seems to be related to how you spawn certain things in an `android environment`. Has probably nothing to do with `mockito` per se, but I am also not sure how you would handle that stuff in an unit test environment. -- The assigning in the setup should not be necesarry, a simply rule based test with annotations does work fine without it.

Comment: If I understood correctly it worked before, so the best option might be to just follow `Maciej Kowalski` advice and set up your mocks manually instead.

Comment: @second, `set up your mocks manually instead.` can you please elaborate this term. How can I mock LoginActivity by setting up mokes manually? How to inject mocks using setter? Should I do that for LoginActivity?

Comment: I added an example as an answer (as code in the comments can't be properly formatted). See it as an extension to `Maciej Kowalski` answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following to setup your mocks manually (without using annotations):

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    loginActivity = loginActivityRule.getActivity();
    loginActivity.fingerPrintHelper = Mockito.mock(FingerPrintHelper.class);
    // ...
}
```

If `loginAcitivy` could be created succesfully before, you should not face a problem now.
And `fingerPrintHelper` seems to be `public` anyway so its easy to set.
But in case you want to do it properly you could just provide a setter.

---

Or if you want to keep the annotation to create `fingerPrintHelper`.

```
@Mock
FingerPrintHelper fingerPrintHelper;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    loginActivity = loginActivityRule.getActivity();
    loginActivity.fingerPrintHelper = fingerPrintHelper;
    // ...
}
```

---

> Still I would like to know the reason behind keeping loginActivity.fingerPrintHelper = fingerPrintHelper line.

A mock does not magically attach itself to any other object.

`@InjectMocks` would do that for you, but Mockito does not seem be able to handle the creation of your `LoginActivity` on its own.

So the only thing you can do is to manually pass the mock to the object under test.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks for the reply. Still I would like to know the reason behind keeping `loginActivity.fingerPrintHelper = fingerPrintHelper` line. As we are already doing `@Mock FingerPrintHelper fingerPrintHelper;` why do we need to add `loginActivity.fingerPrintHelper = fingerPrintHelper` line inside `setUp()`

Comment: Added a short explanation, hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: Hi @second , Please check this question too https://stackoverflow.com/q/58367198/6532155

Answer (score 1):

You are not injecting the mock anywhere in your tests case. I assume a normal instance is created in constructor / factory.

Either use a setter of the SUT or make Mockito inject it for you:

```
@InjectMocks
LoginActivity loginActivity;
```

Using `@Mock` only is not enough.

Comment: @MaciejKowaski Thanks for the reply, after using `@InjectMocks` I am getting below error, 
`org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InjectMocksException:
Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'loginActivity' of type 'class com.mytest.LoginActivity'.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception : Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

Comment: Most likely that class does not have a public no-arg constructor. You need to inject the mock using a setter then

Comment: Hi @Maciej Kowalski how to deal with `MockWebServer` in below case,
https://stackoverflow.com/q/58367198/6532155 ? Please check this question.