# How to mock two APIs with MockWebServer Android test cases

Tags: mockito, android-espresso, android-testing, android-instrumentation, mockwebserver

I am performing instrumentation testing, in that I am invoking one of the activities which call 2 APIs when activity is created.

Now I want to write instrumentation test cases for this activity, where I have to mock the API response with **mockWebServer** of mockito. My mocking code works fine when I call one single API, but it fails when two APIs are getting called simultaneously.

Even there is another scenario let's say, we have API to fetch recent **message data**, but before that, we always **authenticate the user** by sending refresh token.
**In such cases, we need to call API which authenticates the user and then another API to fetch message data.** Hence we need to call 2 APIs one after another, let's say in a single method. How will I mock **authentication API response and messages API response** while writing test cases of that single method?

How should I deal with this issue? Is there any other approach to deal with such a situation where we need to call more than one API at the same time?

Also, I have used `SystemClock.sleep(4000);` as my callbacks were getting performed asynchronously.

Below is my code to mock API:

```
public class MyAPIActivityTest {

@Rule
public InstantTaskExecutorRule mInstantTaskExecutorRule = new InstantTaskExecutorRule();
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MyAPIActivity> myAPIActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MyAPIActivity.class, true, false);

MockWebServer mockWebServer;
@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void checkVisibilityOfTaskListMockedValidData() throws Exception {
    myAPIActivityTestRule.launchActivity(null);
    String fileName = "json_files/valid_api_response.json";
    mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();
    int PORT_NUMBER = 50205;
    mockWebServer.start(PORT_NUMBER);
    ApiUrls.BASE_QUERY_URL = mockWebServer.url("/").toString();
    mockWebServer.enqueue(new MockResponse()
            .setBody(getStringFromFile(getContext(), fileName)));

    SystemClock.sleep(4000);

    Assert.assertEquals(View.VISIBLE, myAPIActivityTestRule.IvDataIsPresent.getVisibility());
    Assert.assertEquals(View.GONE, myAPIActivityTestRule.IvDataNotPresent.getVisibility());
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    mockWebServer.shutdown();
}


public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(line).append(StringCharacters.NEW_LINE);
    }
    reader.close();
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}

public static String getStringFromFile(Context context, String filePath) throws Exception {
    final InputStream stream = context.getResources().getAssets().open(filePath);

    String text = convertStreamToString(stream);
    stream.close();
    return text;
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: After an investigation, I have found the solutions, that's why replying on my question.

1. `Dispatcher ` helps to add more than 1 mocked response
2. `Idling Resources` & `Awaitility library` will help to avoid adding sleep time I.e, `SystemClock.sleep(4000)`
I also have written a blog on this:
https://blog.kiprosh.com/how-to-test-api-response-with-mockwebserver-library/

Comment: Now that you have enough rating points to put an answer, please put your comment in an answer, I almost missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an investigation, I have found the solutions. Hence replying to my question.

1. The Dispatcher helps to add more than 1 mocked response
2. Idling Resources & Awaitility library will help to avoid adding
   sleep time i.e., SystemClock.sleep(4000).

For more details, below blog might help:

https://blog.kiprosh.com/how-to-test-api-response-with-mockwebserver-library/